# Sending 80,000+ emails less than 6 hours

Tags: php, email

As title states, i need to send 80,000 emails within 6 hours. But without causing a huge load on the server while doing so. I don't want to go to a 3rd party emailer, although I would be interested in their delivery times for a mailing list of this size.

PHP, PHPMailer

Any suggestions?

Ok, as everyone seems to think this is suspicious, let me further explain. I send a newsletter once a week to a list of subscribers who have opted-in (legally) to our list. Often times we don't get the copy for our newsletters finalised till the actual day. In most cases, the copy is date sensitive.

Just because someone needs to send alot of emails quickly, doesn't mean its spam related. It's called have a very old and popular website with a large member base.

I have very aware of dealing with bounce backs, spamlists, etc. Just need to think of ways to send quicker. It seems that alot of the 'commercial' grade providers can send something that size in less than 1 hour! I want to do the same.

Comment: That's 3.7 emails a second. It's a big job. I'd highly recommend using a specialist provider: you're going to have to deal with a number of issues, e.g bounces, send errors, getting on spam blacklists, SMTP relay blocks on number of emails sent etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I send 20k newsletter emails once or twice a month (with PHPMailer), and it takes 2.5 hours on the virtual machine we use for this, since they are all unique emails. You have a few options though:

- group the recipients in smaller batches with bcc (only if the e-mails are not recipient specific)
- upgrade you hardware (if you have money and access to it)

Comment: Option 3: Deploy and send from a botnet :)

Comment: @csl I thought that's what "upgrade your hardware" meant! :)

Comment: interesting idea...BCC them...I would have to see if that is allowed/practiced way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

In theory yes you can. In practice you will almost certainly run into problems, even assuming this is legitimate and non-nefarious:

- Send errors. Your code will need to cope with send errors caused by non-existent domains and temporary network issues.
- Bounce rates. Even a high-quality list will see 10% bounces for either non-existing recipients or through spam detection. A shoddier list may see over 50% bounce rate. Can your system handle 40,000 returned emails?
- Your system capability: can it push out 4 emails a second for 6 straight hours without falling over? You will need to build in a recovery mechanism so that you can continue mailing from where you left off.
- SMTP relay caps: if you're using a third party SMTP server to send the mails (e.g your ISP or mail hoster) there will be caps on the number you can send every hour (probably a few hundred)
- How many of these addresses are to the same domains? You may quickly find you end up on spam lists, and not just for the domains to which you are sending.
- If you're running your own SMTP server, how does it rank in spam tests? If it's new or your domain has previously been used for mass mailing you may find you're spammed.
- What's the email content? Do you know whether it will be viewed as spam or not? How many will end up in spam folders? Which leads me to:
- Analytics: you really need good feedback on your mailing metrics. This is a pain to do properly by yourself.

All in all, I would really recommend using a specialist service for this.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) to send out large amounts of promotional mail. It can easily handle the load. Just remember to code your script so that it sends emails by batches. You'll have to speak to your host about this. Ours system used to send out about 1000 every 10 minutes. You'll need to speak to your host to find out what they amount they are ok with.